# Error: reference.class BelongsTo extends Association

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying for the first time the ORM Sequelize and I'm experiencing a problem that I don't know how to solve and hope you can help me. I'm defining some models but when I try to define a belongsTo association, the exception is throwed:

```
throw new Error(this.name + '.' + Utils.lowercaseFirst(Type.toString()) + ' called with something that\'s not a subclass of Sequelize.Model');
      ^

Error: reference.class BelongsTo extends Association {
  constructor(source, target, options) {
    super(source, target, options);

    this.associationType = 'BelongsTo';
    this.isSingleAssociation = true;
    this.foreignKeyAttribute = {};

    if (this.as) {
      this.isAliased = true;
      this.options.name = {
        singular: this.as
      };
    } else {
      this.as = this.target.options.name.singular;
      this.options.name = this.target.options.name;
    }

    if (_.isObject(this.options.foreignKey)) {
      this.foreignKeyAttribute = this.options.foreignKey;
      this.foreignKey = this.foreignKeyAttribute.name || this.foreignKeyAttribute.fieldName;
    } else if (this.options.foreignKey) {
      this.foreignKey = this.options.foreignKey;
    }

    if (!this.foreignKey) {
      this.foreignKey = Utils.camelizeIf(
        [
          Utils.underscoredIf(this.as, this.source.options.underscored),
          this.target.primaryKeyAttribute
        ].join('_'),
        !this.source.options.underscored
      );
    }

    this.identifier = this.foreignKey;

    if (this.source.rawAttributes[this.identifier]) {
      this.identifierField = this.source.rawAttributes[this.identifier].field || this.identifier;
    }

    this.targetKey = this.options.targetKey || this.target.primaryKeyAttribute;
    this.targetKeyField = this.target.rawAttributes[this.targetKey].field || this.targetKey;
    this.targetKeyIsPrimary = this.targetKey === this.target.primaryKeyAttribute;

    this.targetIdentifier = this.targetKey;
    this.associationAccessor = this.as;
    this.options.useHooks = options.useHooks;

    // Get singular name, trying to uppercase the first letter, unless the model forbids it
    const singular = Utils.uppercaseFirst(this.options.name.singular);

    this.accessors = {
      get: 'get' + singular,
      set: 'set' + singular,
      create: 'create' + singular
    };
  }

  // the id is in the source table
  injectAttributes() {
    const newAttributes = {};

    newAttributes[this.foreignKey] = _.defaults({}, this.foreignKeyAttribute, {
      type: this.options.keyType || this.target.rawAttributes[this.targetKey].type,
      allowNull: true
    });

    if (this.options.constraints !== false) {
      const source = this.source.rawAttributes[this.foreignKey] || newAttributes[this.foreignKey];
      this.options.onDelete = this.options.onDelete || (source.allowNull ? 'SET NULL' : 'NO ACTION');
      this.options.onUpdate = this.options.onUpdate || 'CASCADE';
    }

    Helpers.addForeignKeyConstraints(newAttributes[this.foreignKey], this.target, this.source, this.options, this.targetKeyField);
    Utils.mergeDefaults(this.source.rawAttributes, newAttributes);

    this.identifierField = this.source.rawAttributes[this.foreignKey].field || this.foreignKey;

    this.source.refreshAttributes();

    Helpers.checkNamingCollision(this);

    return this;
  }

  mixin(obj) {
    const methods = ['get', 'set', 'create'];

    Helpers.mixinMethods(this, obj, methods);
  }

  /**
   * Get the associated instance.
   *
   * @param {Object} [options]
   * @param {String|Boolean} [options.scope] Apply a scope on the related model, or remove its default scope by passing false.
   * @param {String} [options.schema] Apply a schema on the related model
   * @see {@link Model.findOne} for a full explanation of options
   * @return {Promise<Model>}
   */
  get(instances, options) {
    const association = this;
    const where = {};
    let Target = association.target;
    let instance;

    options = Utils.cloneDeep(options);

    if (options.hasOwnProperty('scope')) {
      if (!options.scope) {
        Target = Target.unscoped();
      } else {
        Target = Target.scope(options.scope);
      }
    }

    if (options.hasOwnProperty('schema')) {
      Target = Target.schema(options.schema, options.schemaDelimiter);
    }

    if (!Array.isArray(instances)) {
      instance = instances;
      instances = undefined;
    }

    if (instances) {
      where[association.targetKey] = {
        [Op.in]: instances.map(instance => instance.get(association.foreignKey))
      };
    } else {
      if (association.targetKeyIsPrimary && !options.where) {
        return Target.findById(instance.get(association.foreignKey), options);
      } else {
        where[association.targetKey] = instance.get(association.foreignKey);
        options.limit = null;
      }
    }

    options.where = options.where ?
      {[Op.and]: [where, options.where]} :
      where;

    if (instances) {
      return Target.findAll(options).then(results => {
        const result = {};
        for (const instance of instances) {
          result[instance.get(association.foreignKey, {raw: true})] = null;
        }

        for (const instance of results) {
          result[instance.get(association.targetKey, {raw: true})] = instance;
        }

        return result;
      });
    }

    return Target.findOne(options);
  }

  /**
   * Set the associated model.
   *
   * @param {Model|String|Number} [newAssociation] An persisted instance or the primary key of an instance to associate with this. Pass `null` or `undefined` to remove the association.
   * @param {Object} [options] Options passed to `this.save`
   * @param {Boolean} [options.save=true] Skip saving this after setting the foreign key if false.
   * @return {Promise}
   */
  set(sourceInstance, associatedInstance, options) {
    const association = this;

    options = options || {};

    let value = associatedInstance;
    if (associatedInstance instanceof association.target) {
      value = associatedInstance[association.targetKey];
    }

    sourceInstance.set(association.foreignKey, value);

    if (options.save === false) return;

    options = _.extend({
      fields: [association.foreignKey],
      allowNull: [association.foreignKey],
      association: true
    }, options);

    // passes the changed field to save, so only that field get updated.
    return sourceInstance.save(options);
  }

  /**
   * Create a new instance of the associated model and associate it with this.
   *
   * @param {Object} [values]
   * @param {Object} [options] Options passed to `target.create` and setAssociation.
   * @see {@link Model#create}  for a full explanation of options
   * @return {Promise}
   */
  create(sourceInstance, values, fieldsOrOptions) {
    const association = this;

    const options = {};

    if ((fieldsOrOptions || {}).transaction instanceof Transaction) {
      options.transaction = fieldsOrOptions.transaction;
    }
    options.logging = (fieldsOrOptions || {}).logging;

    return association.target.create(values, fieldsOrOptions).then(newAssociatedObject =>
      sourceInstance[association.accessors.set](newAssociatedObject, options)
    );
  }
} called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model
    at Function.<anonymous> (/home/wolgan/TCC2/web/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/mixin.js:81:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/wolgan/TCC2/web/models/Reference.js:11:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/wolgan/TCC2/web/models/Project.js:4:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/wolgan/TCC2/web/models/Researcher.js:4:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! web@0.0.0 start: `PORT=8000 node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the web@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/wolgan/.npm/_logs/2018-10-02T17_26_00_132Z-debug.log
```

Using some "console.log debug" I see that the exception happens when the execution reaches the belongsTo here:

```
const Researcher = require('./Researcher');
const Project = sequelize.define('projects', {
  sippee_id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  },
});

console.log(2)
Project.belongsTo(Researcher);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for this error is, you have already included "Project" model in your "Researcher" definition file and declared an association there.
There are several ways you can work around this.

My preferred method, instead of declaring the associations in individual files use another file specifically for that purpose. Export all the models from there. And whenever you need to use models include the file for association. Example:

```
const Researcher = require('./Researcher');
const Project = require('./Project');
Project.belongsTo(Researcher);
Researcher.hasMany(Project);
module.exports = {Researcher:Researcher,Project:Project};
//association.js
```

And in your app.js or other files:

```
const db = require('./db/association.js');
const Researcher = db.Researcher;
const Project = db.Project;
Project.findAll().then(projects => {
   //Your code
})
```

You can also take a look at this example given on Sequelize's official github page:
[Sequelize Express example](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/tree/master/models)